# Three.js loads textures as black color

Tags: javascript, three.js

Code:

```js
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load('resources/earth.png');

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3.7, 32, 32 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture });
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
sphere.position.y=4;
scene.add(sphere);
```

Result: black sphere

Expected result: sphere with texture

I have tried multiple images extensions but results are identical.

Comment: Possibly a CORS error if you don't have access to the file

Comment: I'm pretty sure i have access to the file.

Comment: @TomTruyen also there is no error, texture is just black. Also checked it in 5 browsers, always loads as black.

Comment: Have you looked into other stackoverflow posts. There seem to be quite a few with the same problem

Comment: @TomTruyen all of the answers say "change to png". I wish solution was that easy.

Comment: Any visual changes, if you use `https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg` link instead of `resources/earth.png`?

Comment: @prisoner849 this one works fine.

Comment: If the link that prisoner849 gave you works, that means it's a CORS issue. You can't access images stored in your hard drive because browsers don't allow this. See https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally to run a local host so you can load local images.

Comment: Do you have a render loop? If you're only rendering once then the issue is the texture hasn't finished loading. Textures are loaded asychronously so you either have to keep rendering so eventually the sphere will be drawn with the texture after it has loaded or you have to wait for the texture to load by passing a callback to the loader.

Comment: Make sure the image isn't actually just transparent with black shapes.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a render loop? If you're only rendering once then the issue is the texture hasn't finished loading. Textures are loaded asychronously so you either have to keep rendering so eventually the sphere will be drawn with the texture after it has loaded or you have to wait for the texture to load by passing a callback to the loader.

If I take your code like this I'll get a black sphere

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/build/three.module.js';

function main() {
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  var texture = loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/eCpD7bM.jpg');

  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3.7, 32, 32 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture });
  var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  sphere.position.y=4;
  scene.add(sphere);

  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 500;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 4, 8);
  
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('red');
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

main();
</script>
```

But, if I render in a `requestAnimationFrame` loop I'll get see the texture eventually.

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/build/three.module.js';

function main() {
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  var texture = loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/eCpD7bM.jpg');

  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 3.7, 32, 32 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture });
  var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  sphere.position.y=4;
  scene.add(sphere);

  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 500;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 4, 8);
  
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('red');
  
  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```

If you still don't see a texture locally then, as others have pointed out, to load textures at all in WebGL require you use a web server. There's [a simple one](https://greggman.github.io/servez).

Also learn how to use [the JavaScript console](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-debugging-javascript.html) to see error messages.

Comment: Fixed it by loading image from website.

Comment: I had this issue in a different scenario and this pointed me in the right direction; given that I was rendering a static scene, I wrapped the call to `TextureLoader.load()` in a `Promise` and only proceeded once that had resolved.